# Nearest entry using related entry Smart Map field

Tags: relations, plugin-smartmap

I’m trying to build a query to get the geographically closest entries, based on an Smart Map field value within a related entry.

[image: Diagram of relationships and template]

The following template tags were my first guess, but returned an empty result set.

```
{% set nearest = allUnitsCriteria.relatedPropertyField.smartMapField(params).order('distance') %}
```

What’s the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you referring to the [Smart Map](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/smart-map/) plugin? If so, your code looks correct as per [the example in the docs](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/smart-map/sorting-entries-by-closest-locations/) (assuming field handles are correct). Have you tested whether `allUnitsCriteria` actually returns entries without the `smartAddressField` argument? What happens if you dump `allUnitsCriteria|length`? Also, what does the `params` object you pass to `smartAddressField` contain?

Comment: Thanks, @mmikkel. This is indeed a Smart Map field.

The `allUnitsCriteria` is just a simplification. At present, it’s set to `craft.entries.section('units').limit(null)`. `params` are set to `{ target: '_lat_,_lng_', range: 1000 }`.

The complication here is that the **Unit** entry doesn’t contain an address field, but instead links to a **Property** entry, which does contain an address field.

Answer (score 3):

Being that the `smartMapField` attribute belongs to entries in the `Property` section, and not the entries in the `Unit` section, your current element criteria is a bit off (it basically assumes that the `smartMapField` property is found on the `Unit` entry models).

Basically, you'll need *two* element criterias to accomplish what you want.

The first criteria will pull `Property` entries based on their `smartMapField` value and the `params` object. The second one will pull `Unit` properties, by relation to the `Property` entries in the first criteria.

Finally, we'll need to use the `group` filter to output the unit entries in the correct order (i.e. those related to the nearest property entry first).

Important: It isn't 100% clear from your question, but I'm assuming that the relation between `Units` and `Properties` originates from a `relatedPropertyField` in the `Units` entries, rather than the other way around.

I haven't been able to test this, but I believe something like this should do the trick:

```
{% set nearest = craft.entries.section('units').relatedTo({
    targetElement : craft.entries.section('properties').smartMapField(params).order('distance').limit(null),
    field : 'relatedPropertyField'
}).limit(null).order('targets1.sortOrder')|group('relatedPropertyField.first().id') %}
```

Note the `group` filter applied to the `nearest` variable. This is needed to group the returned entries by their common `Property` relation. The `group` filter turns `nearest` into an array of grouped elements, which means that when you output the entries, you'll need a nested `for` loop:

```
{% for units in nearest %}
    {% for unit in units %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```